# MS Edge Opens 50 Browsers with Logging on Startup

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, microsoft-edge

A few days ago, I started to seeing 50 (I counted) instances of MS Edge opening when I start Windows 10. This has been going on for a couple of weeks now, but there are no message from Avast nor MalwareBytes indicating a virus or issue.

I did some registry digging and found the following multiple entries with the following value:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --type=service --enable-logging --log-level=0 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir27460_924879075" /prefetch:8
```

[image: IMG:]

This was located in:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Is this a screwball move by Microsoft, or should I be concerned?

At this point, I'm deleting them from the registry, but something seems amiss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That registry key `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`  indicates that Windows runs program(s) when you log on. As stated [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys):

> Run and RunOnce registry keys cause programs to run each time that a user logs on. The data value for a key is a command line no longer than 260 characters. Register programs to run by adding entries of the form description-string=commandline. You can write multiple entries under a key. If more than one program is registered under any particular key, the order in which those programs run is indeterminate.
>
> The Windows registry includes the following four keys:
>
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
> - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

Check if the other key mentioned above also have those MS Edge entries.

> Is this a screwball move by Microsoft, or should I be concerned?

I presume an installation, update or even un-install that did not completed properly, and kept adding those entries. It can be Microsoft or any software developers. You should check that if that directory shown on the image exists and what are its contents. If it exists, it can point you to the app that wrote those registry keys

> At this point, I'm deleting them from the registry, but something seems amiss.

If these entries are still on the registry, you can also view them from opening the Task Manager -> Startup. They will be listed there because of `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` . You can disable them for there.

I don't think deleting them should create a problem. But to be on the safer side, export that key to a file before deleting those entries.

Comment: I was able to disable them in Task Manager. I didn't care for the fact that there were 50 of them, so I did remove them from the registry. They were only in the location listed above (not the others you mentioned). Either way, failed installation would make sense. Thanks

Comment: PS, there were 50 of those keys in the registry